# Spring Boot auto-configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

From the documentation:

> Spring Boot auto-configuration attempts to automatically configure
>   your Spring application based on the jar dependencies that you have
>   added. For example, If HSQLDB is on your classpath, and you have not
>   manually configured any database connection beans, then we will
>   auto-configure an in-memory database.

What exactly is auto-configured here (in terms of database configuration)? And how this springboot autoconfiguration works?

Comment: As it stands, this question is really, _really_ broad. If there's something specific you're trying to understand, please rephrase the question to include it.

Comment: for now.. i would like to know about auto configuration in terms of database configuration only... (rephrasing accordingly)

Comment: I would recommend trying some of the spring.io getting started guides to get more familiarity with things before asking such a broad question. Most of what Spring Boot does is based on the Spring framework itself. You would first have to understand that to understand the autoconfiguration (datasources, connection pools, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of AutoConfigurations**

You'll find the list of AutoConfiguration classes => [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/auto-configuration-classes.html) (there are more than a hundred, so I won't paste the list). Most of them (if not all) are triggered `@Conditionally` when specific classes are found on the classpath and/or some beans are defined.

**HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration**

If I take `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` for instance. Without it, you would typically create a `@Configuration` class to define :

- @Bean DataSource;
- @Bean EntityManager;
- @Bean transactionManager;
- probably some hibernate properties.

With `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`, no need to define those, `spring-boot` takes care of it for you. It even tries to determine whether the database connection in your application.properties is for embedded database, and launches it, plus configures the hibernate properties accordingly.

**spring.factories**

`Spring-Boot` loads the `AutoConfigurations` defined in [META-INF/spring.factories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories)(in `spring-boot-autoconfigure` jar).
You could also define your own AutoConfiguration classes in a custom `spring.factories` file. It could be useful if you constantly configure the same beans in a similar way in multiple projects (I've never done that!).

**Recap**

For the most part, an `*-AutoConfiguration` simply sets up `@Beans` that you would otherwise need to setup yourself in a `@Configuration` class. In other words, AutoConfiguration bundle a set of `@Conditional @Beans`. It does it to the best of its knowledge, but you can override them with your own if you wish.

**Additional information**

- [how-springboot-autoconfiguration-magic](http://sivalabs.in/2016/03/how-springboot-autoconfiguration-magic)

Answer (score 0):

For database setup: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

It will give details on specifying application properties and what gets configured automatically.